# Hide an item when is deleted with this.$http.delete()

Tags: vue.js

I have website build with VueJS on frontend and I want to hide each item that is deleted.

I have in store.js a property eventIsActive set to true:

```
export const store =  new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    eventIsActive: true
  }
})
```

In a ShowItems.vue(grid version) I have a the delete method where I set the eventIsActive to false:

```
removeEvent() {
  this.$http.delete('/event/' + item)
  .then((response) => {
    this.$store.state.eventIsActive = false;
    this.$router.push('/events');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alertify.error('Error', error);
  })
}
```

On the same page I have the computed method for this property eventIsActive:

```
computed: {
  getActiveEvent() {
    return this.$store.state.eventIsActive;
  }
}
```

On the HTML for this page I use the method from computed to hide the deleted component.

```
<template>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"  v-if="getActiveEvent">
    <p>{{itemTitle}}</p>
    <p>{{itemSubtitle}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is that when I delete an item, the rest of items are hidden, not only the one that is deleted.

Before I just used a simple eventIsActive: true in data() and set it to false in the removeEvent(). Was easier to use it, but because I have ShowItems.vue(list version), too, if I delete an Item in grid version, in the list version will still be there, until I refresh the page.

Can someone help me in this direction?

Comment: try this to use item in http.delete item.state.eventIsActive = false; and tell us

Comment: that is not a valid sintax my friend

Comment: But I tried to show you: ```TypeError: Cannot set property 'eventIsActive' of undefined```

Comment: item.eventIsActive = false; and this?

Comment: My friend, eventIsActive comes from Vuex store and is not a property for item to use it how you show it.

Comment: as i see the scope of this in http will not the item, is the promise. So in this position you need to create a setter to change the state of item, that my idea

Answer (score 0):

Vuex state is a global state that is shared by all components in the app.

So when you change `eventIsActive` all elements get the same state (true/false) and act accordingly.

Since showing/hiding an item is related to that specific item state, you need to have a local state for each item and change only it.

so in the data attribute of the component, add an active flag and use it instead:

```
data () {
   ....
   active: true
}
....
removeEvent() {
  this.$http.delete('/event/' + item)
  .then((response) => {
    this.active = false;
    this.$router.push('/events');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alertify.error('Error', error);
  })
}
....
<template>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"  v-if="active">
    <p>{{itemTitle}}</p>
    <p>{{itemSubtitle}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is what I tried first time my friend. I said that in the end of my question. The problem is that I have 2 version for the same items page(grid and list). So if I delete an item from the grid list and switch to list version, that item is still on the page, even on the database is not.

Comment: You are using Vuex to hold global state, don't you think the list, which is shared by both the grid and the list, is suitable to be in the vuex state? and then they will both share the same list and have the same items with the same state